# How to check if Django ValidationError subclass was raised?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.6

Let's assume I have a Django model:

```
class MyDjangoModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    attribute = models.IntegerField()

    class CustomValidationError(ValidationError):
        pass

    def clean(self):
        if self.attribute < 1:
            raise CustomValidationError("Attribute should be > 1!")

        if len(self.name) > 20:
            raise ValidationError("Name too long!")
```

I would like to create model instance and validate it:

```
inst = MyDjangoModel(name="Foo", attribute=0)
try:
    inst.full_clean()
except CustomValidationError:
    print("Hello!")
except ValidationError:
    print("Bye!")
```

But the code above will never print `"Hello!"` because `full_clean` method is raising only `ValidationError`.

Can anyone suggest, how to call `full_clean` and check if `ValidationError` subclass exception was raised?

Comment: A simple `except ValidationError` will handle all instances of subclasses as well.

Comment: @schwobaseggl yes, thank You, but I would like to add custom logic when subclass of ValidationError is raised.

Comment: The underlying exceptions are collected in the `full_clean` and still accessible. See the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `full_clean` method collects all the errors raised on several phases.

You can check how it's calling your `clean` method here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L1150

Luckily, the original exceptions are preserved inside `error_dict`.

You can try this:

```
inst = MyDjangoModel(name="Foo", attribute=0)
try:
    inst.full_clean()
except ValidationError as exc:
    for original_exc in exc.error_dict['__all__']:
        if isinstance(original_exc, MyDjangoModel.CustomValidationError):
            print("Hello!")
        elif isinstance(original_exc, ValidationError):
            print("Bye!")
```

Assuming that `CustomValidationError` is only raised from the `clean` method. Otherwise you would also need to check other keys in `error_dict`.

Note that the order of the `if`s is important: the second one would also be True if the first one is True.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach when using `except Exception as e:`:

```py
try:
   ...
except Exception as e:
   if isinstance(e, ValidationError):
       print("Validation error occured")
```

Nb: This is a general answer to do something when a particular type of error is raised